# Protocols 10 to Protools 9

Tags: pro-tools

How to open a ProTools 10 session in Protools 9 when u don't have the higher version of Protools 10 to convert the session from .ptx to .ptf ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 8 and work with an editor regularly who is on 10, and he generates a PTF for me.  No way to open a PTX on 9 or lower.  Something about the file coding is completely different, no way to convert it unless it's done via PT 10 or 11 (and notice how identical sessions in PTX and PTF have drastically different sizes, even on 'blank' sessions.. big tell tale sign that PTX is a whole different animal, especially in that you definitely can't alter the extension to trick it and have it work)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. Somebody will have to convert it for you.